# Understanding variable selection with Random Forest and eXtreme Gradient Boosting

Tags: feature-selection

I already apologize if this topic has already been addressed here, I simply did not find a combination of words that would return what I am looking for.

I'm making selection of variables with the Boruta library for the Random Forest and eXtreme Gradiente Boosting models.

I have 47 variables, some of which are highly correlated. Two in particular draw attention: age and age group.

Would the fact that one is clearly obtained from the other be enough as a criterion to eliminate one? Or can the fact that one is continuous and the other categorical be useful for models?

Furthermore, I would like to understand whether my interpretation of Boruta's selection of variables is correct.

- For Random Forest, Boruta classified both as important. I imagine that this is due to the following fact: As Random Forest grows several trees and the variables in each one of them are randomized, then there are trees where only one of the two is present. And as age and age range are the two best predictors (based on the area of ​​the ROC curve of `filterVarImp` of `caret` and by `information_gain` of `FSelectorRcpp`), it is natural that both are reported as important.
- For eXtreme Gradient Boosting, Boruta classifies only the age group as important. The reason would be because once a tree is grown using the age group, then age will not be able to improve (boosting) and therefore it becomes unnecessary?